# Can tmux and screen generate environment variables that can be used by PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: environment-variables, tmux, gnu-screen

I want to create a log the commands I create in all the termimals I work in, as explained in this question, [Is there some utility or plugin which includes the current directory in the bash history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358790), and in which others have created their own alternatives, eg https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/28/log-bash-history/ and https://github.com/rcaloras/bashhub-client.

I use tmux and session to organize my work, by using session names and window names. It is possible for them to set shell variables that can be used by the `PROMPT_COMMAND` to update the history, namely use the session and window names to create an environment variables in said log. I need to be able to set them at will and switch them on or off as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`screen` sets the environment variables `STY` and `WINDOW` to the full name of the session (as shown by `screen -ls`), and the window number, respectively. Of course, these may change during the execution of the program, and there's no way for `screen` to update the variables stored inside a subprocesses memory.

Comment: Is it possible the other way round, other commands to read screen and tmux variables?