# Can shell history files store additional information besides the timestamp and the command itself?

Tags: command-history

I want to store additional info about the commands I execute in the shell history, namely the `host`, `user`, `pwd`, the `timestamp`and the command itself.

I have recenlty asked some questions about it, eg [Is there some utility or plugin which includes the current directory in the bash history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358790/is-there-some-utility-or-plugin-which-includes-the-current-directory-in-the-bash) and https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/67wdl8/does_zsh_have_the_facility_to_record_more_than/.

Do any of the other shells ie besides `bash`, namely `zsh` and `fish`, have history formats that can include the additional information? The unix.stackexchange question has a an example that will probably break if histories from different sessions are added, and the author says it will be a bit involved if additional information is added to the timestamp line.